# Find a word in a sentence c++

Tags: c++, string, getline

This code should say if a word is present in a sentence or not. When I insert the sentence and the word where I declare the strings(for exemple: string s = "the cat is on the table" string p = "table" the program says that the word is in the sentence) the code works but, with the getline, the for cycle never begin and it always says that the word isn't in the sentence.

Please help I dont know what to do

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {

string s;

string p;

string word;

bool found = false;

int sl = s.length();

int beg = 0;

int pl = p.length();

cout << "sentence: ";

getline(cin, s);

cout << "word: ";

getline(cin, p);

for(int a = 0; a<sl; a++)
{
    if(s[a]== ' ')
{
    word = s.substr(beg, a-beg);
    if (word== p)
    {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
    beg = a+1;
    }
 }

 if (found== true)
 {
    cout <<"word " << p << " is in a sentence " << s;
 }

 else
{
 word = s.substr(beg);

 if (word== p)
    {
      found = true;
    }

if(found == true)
{
    cout <<"the word " << p << " is in the sentence " << s;
}

     else
   {
   cout <<"the word " << p << " isn't in the sentence " << s;
   }

  }
}
```

Comment: You need to compute `sl` *after* you `getline`  the string `s`. Otherwise `sl` is just the size of the default string, which is 0, and so you never enter the loop.

Comment: for the love of all that is holy format your code properly. Every IDE has an autoformatter.  How is this still possible? Do you write code in Notepad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after taking the input strings then use `length()` to find the length, otherwise you are not taking the actual size of the strings.

```
getline(cin, s);
getline(cin, p);

int sl = s.length();

int pl = p.length();
```

For splitting the words after taking the input string by `getline()` you can use `stringstream` which is a builtin c++ function, like :

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string arr;
    getline(cin, arr);

    stringstream ss(arr);
    string word;
     
    while(ss >> word){
       // your desired strings are in `word` one by one
       cout << word << "\n";
    }
}
```

Another thing is that you can declare the strings like `string s, p, word;`

Answer (score 0):

Just use find.

https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

EXAMPLE

```
std::string str ("There are two needles in this haystack with needles.");
std::string str2 ("needle");

// different member versions of find in the same order as above:

std::size_t found = str.find(str2);
if (found!=std::string::npos)
std::cout << "first 'needle' found at: " << found << '\n';
```

END EXAMPLE

Feed it your test string, and your target sub string, and it spits out if the substring is there. Quick and easy.